# Deploy a Javascript Policy in Keycloak 10

Tags: javascript, keycloak, abac

I've followed the [*Create a JAR with the scripts to deploy* instruction](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#create-a-jar-with-the-scripts-to-deploy) to create a custom Javascript policy for checking user attributes and it seems to be deployed successfully, however, **I can't see the policy name in the create policy dropdown**. Is there any setting I need to enable for this feature?

After uploading the `.jar` file to `/keycloak/standalone/deployments`, it says `WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "script.jar" (runtime-name : "script.jar")` without any error. I can also see the `{filename}.jar.deployed` next to my script file.

**Setup:** I use `docker-compose` to launch a `jboss/keycloak` version `10.0.1` container. Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    keycloak:
        image: jboss/keycloak
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        environment:
            KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
            KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        volumes:
            - ./deployments:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments
```

keycloak-scripts.json:

```
{
    "policies": [
        {
            "name": "my-policy",
            "fileName": "my-script-policy.js",
            "description": "My Policy from a JS file"
        }
    ]
}
```

my-script-policy.js:

```
var context = $evaluation.getContext();
var contextAttributes = context.getAttributes();

if (contextAttributes.containsValue('kc.client.network.ip_address', '127.0.0.1')) {
    $evaluation.grant();
}
```

[Client policy setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKY5E.png)

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: This works well for Keycloak 15.0.2. Could you check the options [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/server_installation/topics/profiles.adoc)

Answer (score 1):

It has been a very long time, and I did not use this policy! Yet I managed to create a javascript policy at the time. I believe the issue was the script file name:
[my keycloak-provider repo](https://github.com/behrooz-tahanzadeh/keycloak-providers)

I will try to improve the README file and test it with the latest version of Keycloak to see if it still works.